# go select implementation at runtime without switch statement

Tags: go

I want to select implementation of an interface at runtime, using provided string. I don't want to use switch statement - the code should be generic and work with any new struct implementing the interface without need to modification (open/closed).

Let's say I have following structure:

```
type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct{}

func (_ *A) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Calling A")
}

type B struct{}

func (_ *B) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Calling B")
}

type C struct{}

func (_ *C) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Calling C")
}
```

Then, I'd like to do something like:

```
func main() {
    // let's pretend it's user input
    input := []string{"C", "A", "C"}

    for _, className := range input {
        // struct := StructFromName(className)
        // struct.Foo()
    }
}
```

To print:

```
Calling C
Calling A
Calling C
```

https://play.golang.org/p/mOW5miz5LdU

To my disappointment, go runtime keeps no registry of struct names and as a result, no `StructFromName(className)` is available. I wouldn't like to create such registry by my own as well.
Disclaimer: I write mainly in java and I have OOP habits, so I expected something as easy as

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
Foo foo = (Foo) object;
foo.Foo();
```

I tried another approach, with methods instead of interface, and it works but it feels hacky and non-idiomatic:

```
type Hack struct{}

func (_ *Hack) FooA() {
    fmt.Println("Calling A")
}

func (_ *Hack) FooB() {
    fmt.Println("Calling B")
}

func (_ *Hack) FooC() {
    fmt.Println("Calling C")
}

func main() {
    hack := &Hack{}

    // let's pretend it's user input
    input := []string{"FooC", "FooA", "FooC"}

    for _, funcName := range input {
        reflect.ValueOf(hack).MethodByName(funcName).Call(nil)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3ueEuVV2Hx9

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think go creators had a good reason not to implement such registry; moreover, in my case, the registry of existing types is a little bit overkill. And if I had to register only the types I want, I'd need to either know these types in advance - it's a closed circle.

Comment: I disagree with the reflection part but it isn't a place to discuss. <Misclicked enter here, so editing> However, I implemented such a registry using your sql example, so thank you for that suggestion - it's not exactly what I wanted but it'll do. I totally missed the fact that init() functionality exists.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that will work for you, even if it's not what you had in mind.

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer, since it seems they were helpful enough.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to this type of thing is indeed a registry.  I suggest using the registry in the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package of the standard library for guidance.

Each SQL driver (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc), registers itself in its own `init()` function by calling [`sql.Register`](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=1039:1087#L34).

This makes for a clean dependency tree (no circular dependencies), and allows for ad-hoc implementations of your type, possibly even from third parties.